# Microsoft-IIS/6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

Does anyone know if a server that is Microsoft-IIS/6.0 support ASP files? I can't find an answer.

Should have been more specified. Does it support .aspx files?

Answer (score 2):

Yes IIS 6.0 supports Classic ASP, ASP.NET 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0

[Enabling ASP Pages in IIS 6.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737992%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: And ASP.NET 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5